# how to insert a value into a postgresql database table through a variable

Tags: python, database, postgresql, insert

```
import psycopg2

title = 'a'
author = 'b'
genre = 'c'
isbn = 23
year_of_publication = 2012
borrow_status = 'available'
return_date = None

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='lincoln_library', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='Akkada_AI')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO books(title, author, genre, isbn, year_of_publication, borrow_status, return_date)
    VALUES (title, author, genre, isbn, year_of_publication, borrow_status, return_date);
""")
print(cur.fetchall())
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I want to insert the values of this set of variables , like title, author .... into the table called books of the database called lincoln variable.

it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\DATA SCIENCE\Python Crash Course\PART II-PROJECTS\Library Management System\book_database.py", line 15, in <module>
    cur.execute("""
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "title" does not exist
LINE 3:     VALUES (title, author, genre, isbn, year_of_publication,...
                    ^
DETAIL:  There is a column named "title" in table "books", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do i go about it?

Comment: The linked duplicate shows you how.  You should also review [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#basic-module-usage).